# MySQL JSON Path with semicolon in element

Tags: mysql, json

If I have a JSON doc like this:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "foo:oo": "bar2"
}
```

I can access the property "foo" with:

```
SELECT col->"$.foo" // Outputs "bar"
```

However, if I try to access the property named "foo:oo" like so:

```
SELECT col->"$.foo:oo" // Should output "bar2", but triggers an error
```

I get the following error:

`Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 8.`

How can I access a property that has a semicolon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT col->"$foo:oo" // Should output "bar2", but triggers an error
```

You are missing a dot:

`SELECT col->"$.foo:oo"`

I got this to work in an online mysql environment:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (sentence JSON);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('{"foo": "bar", "foo:oo": "bar2"}');    
SELECT sentence ->> '$."foo:oo"' FROM t1;
```

Comment: I'm sorry. It was a typo on my post. I am using the dot. Edited.

Comment: It works on http://jsonpath.com/. Have you tried the bracket notation $.['foo:oo']? It's probably confused by ":". Note: I would also try double quotation if single quotes are not working.

Comment: Updated my answer.